# How to stop portrait and upside down on ios7 simulator in xcode5?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My program only use landscape mode. earlier i used xcode 4.5 but now it not working now i used xcode 5. simulator it rotating four sides.

i need only landscape left and right only.

in my app delegate i put

```
 - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;//|UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ||
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft );
}


-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else{
        return NO;
    }
}
```

in my every viewcontroller i put

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

[image]

every storyboard viewconrtoller and navigation view contriller i setup like this. 
[image]
how can i solve this problem

Comment: Are you using UITabBarController as rootViewController?

Comment: i used uinavigationcontrol

Comment: Might be u are adding `UINavigationController` as `subView` in `appDelegate`. Try to add `UINavigationController` as `rootViewController` in `appDelegate`

Comment: Please tell me how can i do it

Comment: The `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method isn't used in iOS 6 and later.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add your Top Most controller as rootViewController in appDelegate like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {  
        navigation=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];  
        [self.window setRootViewController:navigation];  
    }
```